# (Python) If I have a point (0,0), how can I change the x value of that point by a given number

Tags: python

I have a point (0,0), and I want to increase the x coordinate of that point by a value that a user will specify.

```
def change_coordinates():
    origin = (0,0)
    x = input("By how much do you want to increase the x value?")
    # here I need a code that would change origin from (0,0) to (0+x,0)
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you use python 2.7.3 or below:

```
origin = (origin[0] + x, origin[1])
```

If your version of python is greater then 3:

```
origin = (origin[0] + int(x), origin[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
position = (1, 2)
x, y = position
position = (x + 3, y)
# now position is (4, 2)
```